# Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in a code that worked

Tags: php

We have a system at work that gets a list of ips from a url and outputs the location of those ips. I didn't wrote it and the guy that did is gone (I have access to the code). The problem is that all of a sudden I'm getting the above error. I was wondering, without getting too specific into the code (but i'm more than willing), how is that possible if no one touched the code.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code and a list of sample inputs that you are getting for this code.

Comment: Perhaps the url that return you the list of ips and the others informations has change the way the data is return.

Comment: If no one touched the code probably the url is changed.

Comment: The url is just a txt file with ips. Here's a part of the code: http://pastebin.com/kRmSxfhc (I hope it's ok using pastebin. the code was too long for a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 5.4 now throws errors related to these. 5.3 silently failed

Comment: The system stopped working so i added `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the code to see what's wrong. You're saying that there's a good chance it worked with those errors and that isn't what's wrong? (also, the php version was never updated)

Comment: without code, there is no way anyone can help you fix this :)

Comment: I posted the problematic part of the code above.

Comment: So it's very likely that your csvstr_arr function is not returning what you're expecting, or the webservice you're calling is not returning what you think it does.